# Winners message wont send

Tags: python, discord.py

```py
def convert(time):
        time_dict = {"s": "seconds", "m": "minutes", "h": "hours", "d": "days"} # pulling your idea, but replacing the seconds with the full name of the acronym.
    
        val = time[:-1] # everything before the last character
        unit = time[-1] # the last character

        return f"{val} {time_dict[unit]}" 

convert("5d") # 5 days
convert("10s") # 10 seconds



@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def gcreate(ctx, time: str, *, prize: str):
    time = convert(time)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=prize,
                          description=f"Hosted by - {ctx.author.mention} React with :tada: to enter! Time Remaining: **{time}**",
                          colour = discord.Colour.purple())

    msg = await ctx.channel.send(content=":tada: **GIVEAWAY** :tada:", embed=embed)
    await msg.add_reaction("")

    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    await asyncio.sleep(int(time))

    new_msg = await ctx.channel.fetch_message(msg.id)

    user_list = [user for user in await new_msg.reactions[0].users().flatten() if
                 user != client.user]  
    if len(user_list) == 0:
        await ctx.send("No one reacted.")
    else:
        winner = random.choice(user_list)
        await ctx.send(f"{winner.mention} You have won the {prize}!")
```

I get no errors, it just won't send the winner message.

Comment: Any error ??, You need to send error or else we can't do anything

Comment: @DjWalkzz i get no errors just wont send the winner message

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see which part of code is executed and what you have in variables - it is called `"print debuging"`